# jQuery Laravel PHP :checked is not active after search

Tags: jquery, laravel, checkbox

I have implemented searching on my page. When someone checked a few possibilities to the filtering page, and click 'search', then my page is refreshing and all the inputs that were checked before are gone.

How to stay checked after filtering? Here is my code :

Js:

```
$('.checked').click(function(){
    if (!($(this).is(':checked'))) {
        $(this).prev().removeClass('aktywnyFiltr');
    } else {
        $(this).prev().addClass('aktywnyFiltr');
    }
    return true;
});
```

View:

```
@foreach($colors as $color)
<li>
{!! Form::label('colorName'.$color->id, $color->name, ['class' => 'tekst-filtr opis-koloru checked']) !!}
{!! Form::checkbox('colorValue[]', $color->id, false, ['style' => '', id' => 'colorName'.$color->id, 'class' => 'checked' ]) !!}
</li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to hold your checked `colorValue` checkbox with search result and use that values while render search result:

**How to hold at controller:**

```
$arrSelectedColor = $request->colorValue;
```

And return this `arrSelectedColor` into view.

**How use that value to display check box selected:**

```
{!! Form::checkbox('colorValue[]', $color->id, false, ['style' => '', 'id' => 'colorName'.$color->id, 'class' => 'checked', (in_array($color->id, $arrSelectedColor) ? 'checked' => 'checked' : '')]) !!}
```

Hope you find your solution with this

**UPDATE**

```
{!! Form::checkbox('colorValue[]', $color->id, (in_array($color->id, $arrSelectedColor), ['style' => '', 'id' => 'colorName'.$color->id, 'class' => 'checked']) !!}
```

Comment: Here is some problem : 'checked' => 'checked' : '') in my View

Comment: @wenus: Check *UPDATE*